# Set post terms by term id

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to add post to custom terms within a custom taxonomy. Not sure if I'm tackling this right. So far we have the custom taxomony 'warehouse', and the custom term 'Old Stock'.

Problem is that when I try to add the term to the post using the term_id then it creates a new term with the id as a name. Here is the code I'm using:

```
//add new product
    $id = @wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_title' => $name,
        'post_content' => $desc,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_parent' => $parent,
        'tax_input' => array(
            array(
                'warehouse' => $parent
            ))
        ), true);

    //set terms
    wp_set_object_terms($id, array($parent), "warehouse");
```

As you can see I've tried adding the term_id as '`post_parent`' as '`tax_input`' and also using '`wp_set_object_terms`'

If the term_id was 25, then the above would create a new term called "25"! Instead of sticking the post into the term with an id of 25.

Any help would be appreciated,
cheers

Comment: Are you using a custom post type? And what is the difference between custom taxonomy and custom term?

Comment: the taxonomy is the group name and the term is the term. But found a solution, if I casted the parent as int it worked. So changing last line to:

`wp_set_object_terms($id, (int)$parent, "warehouse");`

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump()` of the `$parent` before `wp_set_object_terms()`, please? Something must be wrong, if it works now, might not work tomorrow... really interested in why it worked by casting to `int`.

Comment: @Soulseekah the $parent was coming straight from $_POST, taken from a jquery post. Could've been a newline character from my js being carried across. The post was being created successfully, just term wasn't been added

Comment: @Coombsey, great! Please include an explanation of this in your answer, so that people who stumble upon the same problem can understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with this, it turned out that the $parent var had to be casted as an int. Looking at the function wp_set_object_terms, it tests the param $parent with is_int(). The var $parent was coming from $_POST which was sent though http post using ajax.

Somewhere along the way, probably on the javascript side, my int $parent was being casted as a string. I'm presuming a new line character or something was being added to the var thus making php think it was a string.

Solution was then to cast the var $parent as an int like so: `(int)$parent`

So changing the last line to

```
wp_set_object_terms($id, (int)$parent, "warehouse");
```

Solved the problem ;)

Comment: select your answer as correct answer if it solves your issue.